# How to logout from site?

Tags: codeigniter

How to logout from all pages of view, when I click on logout link I just from only one page when I am trying to logout from another page its not work.

My controller code is:

```
public function do_login()
{
    $this->user = $this->input->post('user_email',TRUE);
    $this->pass = $this->input->post('user_pass',TRUE);
    $this->pass=md5(sha1(sha1($this->pass)));

    $u = new User();
    $login_data = array('email' => $this->user, 'password' => $this->pass);
    $u->where($login_data)->get();

    if(!empty($u->id) && $u->id > 0 )
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $u->id;
        $_SESSION['user_name']= $u->username;
        $_SESSION['fullname']= $u->fullname;
        $_SESSION['is_verefied'] = $u->active;
        $_SESSION['user_email']= $u->email;

        $u->lastlogin = time();
        $u->save();
        setcookie("logged", 1, time()+86400);

        if(empty($_POST['referer']))
        {
            if(empty($_GET['referer']))
            {
                $url = "./";
            }
            else
            {
                $url = $_GET['referer'];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $url = $_POST['referer'];
        }
        redirect($url);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->template->set_layout('inner');
        $this->template->build('login_view',$this->data);
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    setcookie("logged", 0, time()+86400);
    $_COOKIE["logged"] = '';

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
    $_SESSION['user_name']= '';
    $_SESSION['fullname']= '';
    $_SESSION['is_verefied'] = '';
    $_SESSION['user_email']= '';

    redirect('./home/index/logout');
}
```

When I logout from site, and click back from browser the user information session its not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The back button of your browser might get you to cached version of you page, cached from back when you were logged it. Also, I suggest you use [CodeIgniter's sessions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).

To make sure you're doing everything right.

Destroy the session:

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

Clear the cookie, make sure you use *the same domain* as when you set it up, and that the time is set to past:

```
setcookie('logged', '', time()-3600); // minus one hour
```

Comment: i will try use `setcookie('logged', '', time()-3600); // minus one hour
  $this->session->sess_destroy();
  $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
  $this->session->unset_userdata('user_name');
  $this->session->unset_userdata('fullname');
  $this->session->unset_userdata('is_verefied');
  $this->session->unset_userdata('user_email');` but not work yet

Comment: You don't need the unset parts, just what I wrote you. Note that you need to use CI session to set the data because CI sessions are different than PHP sessions. How do you check if a user is logged in?

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
  {
   $this->template->set_layout('default');
   $this->template->build('home_view',$this->data);
  }
  else{
   $this->template->set_layout('reg');
   $data['title']= 'Registration';
   $this->template->build('registration_view',$this->data);
  }`

Comment: I said you can't combine PHP and CI sessions. `$_SESSION['x']` needs to become `$this->session->userdata('x')` if you want to use CI sessions. Open the link in my answer.

Comment: ok i will try this `if(isset($this->session->userdata('user_id')) || !empty($this->session->userdata('user_id')))` but when open my site i see this error `Can't use method return value in write context`

Comment: `if($this->session->userdata('user_id'))` is enough to check it. Please read the link I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

This script will log the user out of all pages that have a session started on them. You know a page uses sessions if this code is at the top of the code for that page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Logging out of a website is simply clearing any session data and then destroying it.

Try the following in your logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

// what were doing here is checking for any cookies used by the session. 
//If there are any, we are going to delete the data with it.
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
$params["path"], $params["domain"],
$params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
);
}

//now lets unset the session and destroy it

session_unset();
session_destroy();

// for the redirect, we simple use the php header to send the redirect url to the browser

header("Location: login");
```

Make sure when using the header function that there is no output, caused by blank spaces or html. As a logout page, there should be no output anyways since navigating to the logout page should log the user out and immediately redirect.

I use this script on all my sites and it works great. Anywhere I want the logout link to appear, I just link to the page as such:
    Logout

Just make a file called logout.php and put this code into it.

Hope this helps you!